# Pandas String Series, return string if length equals number, otherwise return empty string

Tags: python, pandas, string, conditional-statements, series

I have a Pandas string series as the following:

```
s = pd.Series(["12345678.0","45678912.0", "0", "2983129416.0", "62441626.0"])
```

I first of all must cut the decimal part, and then...

```
result = s.str.split(".", 1, expand=True)[0]
```

I want to find a way to return the string if that's length is 8, otherwise return empty string: ""

```
s[s.str.len() == 8]
```

Of course, this only would keep the strings that's length is 8, but I need empty strings added to fields where they are not 8 characters long. I couldn't figure out by myself how should this be done properly, so thanks in advance for all the ideas!

Expected result:

```
s = pd.Series(["12345678","45678912", "", "", "62441626"])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas Series object has a [`where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) method that you can use after you've split the strings on the `.` character.

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series(["12345678.0","45678912.0", "0", "2983129416.0", "62441626.0"])
s = s.str.split(".", 1, expand=True)[0]
print(s)

result = s.where(s.str.len() == 8, "")
print(result)
```

The `where` method takes a condition and an `other` argument. If the condition is true, it returns the value from the series. If it's false it returns the `other` value.

Output:

```
0      12345678
1      45678912
2             0
3    2983129416
4      62441626
Name: 0, dtype: object

0    12345678
1    45678912
2            
3            
4    62441626
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

s = pd.Series(["12345678.0","45678912.0", "0", "2983129416.0", "62441626.0"])

# Cut the decimal part
result = s.str.split(".", 1, expand=True)[0]

# Use np.where() to return a new series with the desired output
result = np.where(result.str.len() == 8, result, '')

#or 

#result = result.apply(lambda x: x if len(x) == 8 else "")

print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expression: search for strings that are 8 digits long from start of the string to the end (ignoring the part after `.`):

```py
print( s.str.extract(r'^(\d{8})(?:\.\d+)?$').fillna('') )
```

Prints:

```
          0
0  12345678
1  45678912
2          
3          
4  62441626
```